# lunarvim excepts to insert jj so fast

Tags: neovim

I'm using lunarvim and the `ESC` key is mapped to `jj`, `jk` and `kj`. Mostly I used `jj` in my neovim to exit the insert mode. but now here Lunarvim excepts to `jj/kj/jk` be insert so fast as I press `j` twice fast but again it's not enough! while i keep `j` pressing it works and exits the **insert** mode.

I want lunarvim to wait(milliseconds) as I could enter the second `j`.

Comment: What the hell is "lunarvim"?

Comment: https://www.lunarvim.org/, it's an IDE layer for Neovim.

Comment: See https://www.lunarvim.org/community/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your config: `vim.cmd("set timeoutlen=300")`

Answer (score 1):

set `timeoutlen` in your lunarvim **config**. to open config file, press `space + L + c` and add this:

```
vim.opt.timeoutlen = 300
```